# static generic fields in generic classes

Tags: c#, .net, clr

As I know when occured first call for type in C#, CLR find this type and create object-type for this type that contains type-object pointer,sync-block indexer,static fields,methods table(more info in chapter 4 of 'CLR via C#' book).Okay, some generic type have static generic fields.We set values for this fields

```
GenericTypesClass<string, string>.firstField = "firstField";
GenericTypesClass<string, string>.secondField = "secondField";
```

and again

```
GenericTypesClass<int, int>.firstField = 1;
GenericTypesClass<int, int>.secondField = 2;
```

after that on heap created two different object-types or no?

Here more examles:

```
class Simple
{
}

class GenericTypesClass<Type1,Type2>
{
    public static Type1 firstField;
    public static Type2 secondField;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //first call GenericTypesClass, create object-type
        Type type = typeof (GenericTypesClass<,>);

        //create new object-type GenericTypesClass<string, string> on heap
        //object-type contains type-object pointer,sync-block indexer,static fields,methods table(from  Jeffrey Richter : Clr Via C#(chapter 4))
        GenericTypesClass<string, string>.firstField = "firstField";
        GenericTypesClass<string, string>.secondField = "secondField";

        //Ok, this will create another object-type?
        GenericTypesClass<int, int>.firstField = 1;
        GenericTypesClass<int, int>.secondField = 2;

        //and another object-type?
        GenericTypesClass<Simple,Simple>.firstField = new Simple();
        GenericTypesClass<Simple, Simple>.secondField = new Simple();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When a generic type is first constructed with a value type as a parameter, the runtime creates a specialized generic type with the supplied parameter or parameters substituted in the appropriate locations in the MSIL. Specialized generic types are created one time for each unique value type that is used as a parameter ([from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a6ta2h.aspx)).

So every time you use differently parameterized generic type, runtime will create a new a specialized version of it, not sure that it will store it in heap, but it definitely will store it somewhere.

So in your code three types will be created: `GenericTypesClass<string, string>`, `GenericTypesClass<int, int>` and `GenericTypesClass<Simple,Simple>`